# Displaying a Google calendar in a Plone site

Tags: plone, google-calendar-api

What's the recommended way to display the contents of a google calendar in a Plone site? Ideally the entries in the google calendar should act as kind of *virtual* events in Plone.

I do not like to generate events out of google calendar like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/p4a.plonecalendar does, it's more just using the data from google calendar. Any changes in google calendar should be reflected on the plone site without any manual interaction.

Comment: Just embed the calendar maybe: http://google.about.com/od/toolsfortheoffice/ss/embedCalendar.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply embedding fullcalendar.js on your site and displaying the events there:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/

This does not mirror event data to Plone, simply pulls data from live Google Calendar JavaScript APIs and displays them in a pretty box.